# smarty foreach database fetch_assoc

Tags: php, smarty

I am receiving a syntax error from this following peace of code using smarty template. How can I fix it?

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

```
{foreach from=autoLoader::getLibrary('database')->assoc("SELECT * FROM cms_news") item=news}
```

I am trying to look through a mysqli fetch_assoc function.

```
public function assoc($queryText) {
        return $this->query($queryText)->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

Comment: `Smarty` is a template engine; it is used to display the output of your application. The database is a form of persistence. Output and persistence don't have any reason to appear in the same sentence (some applications don't even implement persistence). Don't mix them. Handle the persistence from the PHP code, get some data, send it to Smarty for display. Don't put application logic in the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Keep things simple, don't try to call the function from the template, instead, in your php script assign the results to a variable and pass this variable to smarty. Making a query in a template is bad practice